# Как работают evercookie?

Tags: веб-программирование, cookie

Судя по статьям в интернете, evercookie раскидывают себя повсюду захламляя компьютер. И Что их практически невозможно удалить, потому что они снова появятся. Но как такое возможно, для этого же по идее нужно установить у себя какой-то плагин добровольно, чтобы он постоянно генерил новые evercookie? Или как вообще эта технология работает? Неужели современные браузеры не могут противостоять evercookie?

Comment: Я вам, кажется, уже кидал ссылку на [список механизмов сохранения](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie#browser-storage-mechanisms).

Comment: D-side И что, там все по английски и ничего не понятно. Можете нормально объяснить как это работает?

Comment: @Mike Обычные куки не являются проблемой но evercookie очень даже проблемны, потому что не удаляемы. Т.е. они все же записываются в определенные разрешенные для браузера места (типа кеш, куки, storage). Если я это все удалю, они же должны исчезнуть верно? И если я больше не буду посещать тот сайт, с которого они приходят, то они больше не смогут генериться, верно? т.е. не будет передан js код браузеру? Если не так, то, реально не пойму, что заставляет генерить эти куки, кто-нибудь знает?

Comment: Собственно, библиотека `evercookie`, подключенная на страницу, и заставляет. Да, если удалить все, они исчезнут. Но это сделать очень непросто.

Comment: @Mike  Смысл может и был бы, но как я вообще узнаю, что они у меня есть, если их нереально обнаружить и удалить? Я пользуюсь интернетом, но даже не знаю есть ли у меня evercookies. И их поведение вообще напоминает вирусы. И как я найду этот сайт, который их использует. Если я зайду на сайт, который использует данную технологию, я увижу, что он использует evercookies или там все скрыто в этом плане? И почему они не используются повсеместно, сложно реализовать или что? По описанию, это же реально классная штука, неубиваемые куки, позволяет разделять уникальных пользователей очень точно.

Comment: Это библиотека. Что записывать этим evercookie, решает пользователь библиотеки. Так что да, можно от балды. Механизмы хранения там все задокументированы, если этого мало, есть и исходники. Это никакая не секретная хакерская техника, ознакомиться и пользоваться ею может любой желающий.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72624/discussion-on-question-by-----evercookie).